# How to create a tag using css

Tags: css, styles

I saw following image on a site ,

[image: Tag]

they are not using any background image , doing all this with css   .
How can i create a tag like this using css , suppose there is no `Buy!` button in it ..

here is the link

[Link to image](http://www.groupon.com/deals/happy-hummus-hut-1?c=all&p=0)

Thanks,

Comment: If it is done with CSS, you should be able to find out how they did it by checking out the source of the webpage.

Comment: used to this http://tinkerbin.com/2YhfAxW8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed an image. But just to prove that it is also possible only using css, here is a fiddle solution : http://jsfiddle.net/bspbg/

```
input{
    background-color:rgba(110, 180, 60, 1);
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:40px;
    border-color:white;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    font-size:2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: white;
    margin:20px;
    margin-left: 70px;
    box-shadow:-2px -2px 1px 3px rgba(50, 150, 30,1) inset,5px 5px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255,0.5) inset;
}
.somebg{
    background-color: rgba(100, 200, 230, 1);
    width: 250px;
    height: 105px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(1,1,1,0.5) inset;
}
```

Here the `input` is the button. Play with the borders, the radius and the box-shadows, and you're done :)

EDIT: [new fiddle with background](http://jsfiddle.net/bspbg/2/)

Comment: its ok , but image not like arrow , its simply a rectangle , as you can see in my question the image attached is arrow type , how can i make it like arrow ?

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't get it was the background you needed. I'll try that and come back with a solution !

Comment: @Andy green color should not show anywhere except inside the circle

Comment: i mean to say that in the above fiddle you make arrow perfectly but at right side its showing green color where arrow end it should be transparent so that it will inherit any color where i apply it

Answer (score 4):

They are using background images in the form of sprites.

Here is the sprite: http://assets2.grouponcdn.com/images/groupon/common-s587a68dd07.png?L4HgENCa

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `content: "<p>Any html you like</p>"` command in CSS to render content inside a tag.

Comment: I think Smartboy is talking about the layout of the whole image being done in CSS...

Comment: After adding the content via CSS, its style can be modified by the same CSS file

Comment: @parker.sikand I'm wondering if `content` could have its own `content`. In that case, CSS might be actually turing-complete ;-)